# Provide edit access to php files in server to users acrss sites

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I have the situation of editing the php files in the "www" folder of a server from local machines. But in my condition, all the users across the sites, who shares the intranet, should be able to access the php files. Its more like I'm counting how many times users using an application which I developed. So, my idea is like creating a database in WAMP in the server and creating a php file which performs appending operation. So, if the user uses my application, I will make the php file I created to run in the server and that counts number of times my application used. I'm new to web design and I'm using Apache2.4 version. Please let me know if you have a better approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not quite clear about what your are asking. You could use PHP to count every request and save it into your database.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply.My situation is to edit the php files placed in the server, from my local machine. The server and my machine is linked with intranet. Please let me know how can I achieve this. Please bear me because I'm very new to this area. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give more information so others can help? How do you edit php files placed in the server from your local machine?

Comment: Hello Andy, that's the question I have actually. Lets say I have the database created in the WAMP, in the server machine. Now I have to edit the php files which resides in "www" folder in the server machine, from my local machine. As I mentioned, my local machine and server machine shares same intranet. Now how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "edit the php files which resides in the server" ?

Comment: Hi Andy, I'm sorry, its to run the php files in the server machine, not edit. its my bad..

Comment: you could try looking at this : http://www.php.net/tut.php

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/

Comment: Thanks for your help Andy. Thanks for bearing me..

Comment: Frame your question with a meaning.

Answer (score 0):

say it's filename.php

### filename.php

```
$con=mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("user_db");
$sql="update usage_count set count=count+1";
mysql_query($sql);
```

This code increases the hit-count(**count** as in database) each time the file is fetched from clint computer.